# Dropping a preposition

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions

> Uncle Vernon made another funny noise, like a mouse being trodden
>   **on**.
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Can *on* at the end of the sentence be dropped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trodden is defined (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/trodden), "to step or walk, esp. so as to press, crush, or injure something; trample (usu. fol. by on or upon)."
'**usually** followed by on or upon' implies that it is **occasionally** used without 'on' or 'upon.'

That being said, I was unable to find a decent example of the word being used in this manner without being followed by 'on' or 'upon.'

I don't think the example sentence would lose any meaning if you dropped the 'on,' but it would sound unusual.

Comment: I would put *trodden down* (and the derived word *downtrodden*) under the "trampled" sense as well.  Although *trodden* can appear without a preposition (most commonly in the phrase *the trodden path*), it generally means "formed by many steps" rather than "trampled".  I would say dropping the preposition when you mean "trampled" is chiefly [historic or poetical](http://goo.gl/nOniG)--and it's probably ungrammatical for most speakers today.

Comment: + 1 One may *tread* a surface (such as a floor) or a path (which may be figurative, as in a dance), but such transitive senses as are now represented with *on* *upon* or *down* have not been current since the 18th century. See [*OED 1*](http://archive.org/stream/newenglishdictio101murruoft#page/n313/mode/2up).

Answer (score 4):

No, not in this case and as I far as I know you can't in any context similar to this one.

Here, the meaning of `"trodden on"` means `"to tread on"`. Omission of the `"on"` removes all context and sense from the sentence.